# PHP REST Service is really slow

Tags: php, json, rest, flightphp

I'm having a problem with my PHP REST service, it is really slow.
I build it with the Flight PHP Framework. It's accessing data from a MySQL database and returns them as json.

Flight REST Service:

```
Flight::route('GET /categories', function(){
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $db = Flight::db();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode($result);
    $db = null;
});
```

The first response is very fast and the answer is returned not formatted. 
[image]

After ~3 seconds the request is finished and the answer is displayed correctly.
[image]

Why does it takes so long for finishing the request?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if you do a request which does not require a database? Eg. return a hard-coded string like hello world? That way you can determine if the database data retrieval is the bottleneck.

Comment: Just a long shot but if you do $db->query instead of the prepare-execute,any change?

Comment: Have you tried restarting you server. Also check for throttling in Chrome dev settings

Comment: @peter: i'm not able to restart the server because it's from a webhoster

Comment: @Mihai: doesn't change anything, still takes 3 seconds until finishing the request

Comment: @ThomasMX: the database is fast enough, I already checked that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed that behavior with an `exit();` call at the end of the method:

```
Flight::route('GET /categories', function(){
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   $db = Flight::db();
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
   $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
   echo json_encode($result);
   $db = null;
   exit();
});
```

It takes between 50-80ms for finishing the request now.